Does $\alpha\leq \beta+ \gamma$ imply $\sin \alpha \leq \sin \beta+\sin\gamma$?
Here is the question: Suppose that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\alpha\leq \beta + \gamma$. Is it true that $\sin \alpha \leq \sin \beta+\sin\gamma$? I do not really know how to solve this one. I would be grateful for any hints.

On that interval $\sin$ is increasing, so $\sin(\alpha)  \leq \sin(\beta + \gamma)$.  Can you then make use of the angle-sum identity or something?

Ah right, $\beta+ \gamma$ could exceed that range of monotonicity.

Use the double angle formula and the sine sum formula and then $\alpha/2 \le (\beta+\gamma)/2$ while sine increasing and similarly $\alpha/2 \ge |\beta-\gamma|/2$ and cosine decreasing (if $\alpha\le \beta$ the inequality trivial and same if $\alpha\le\gamma$)

@Conrad: Great! Thanks for your answer.

Alternative way: WLOG, assume that $\beta \le \gamma$. If $\alpha \le \gamma$, true.
If $\alpha > \gamma$, we have
$\sin\alpha - \sin \gamma = 2\cos\frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2}\sin \frac{\alpha - \gamma}{2}
\le 2\cos \frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2}\sin \frac{\beta}{2} \le 2\cos \frac{\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\beta}{2} = \sin \beta$.

For $0\leqslant x\leqslant\pi/2$ we have $\sin x\geqslant 2x/\pi$ (by the concavity of $\sin$).
Hence, if $\beta+\gamma\geqslant\pi/2$ then $\sin\beta+\sin\gamma\geqslant 1$ (and we're done).
Otherwise, by the monotonicity of $\sin$,
$$
\sin\alpha\leqslant\sin(\beta+\gamma)=\sin\beta\color{gray}{\cos\gamma}+\color{gray}{\cos\beta}\sin\gamma\leqslant\sin\beta+\sin\gamma.
$$

Please, do not answer very low-quality questions.
